# Inherit Class of LabelBinarizer with "maximum recursion depth exceede" error

Tags: python, inheritance, recursion, scikit-learn, pipeline

I created a customized encoder class from LabelBinarizer. Here's what it looks like

```
class my_lb(LabelBinarizer):

  def fit(self, X, y=None):
    self.fit(X)

  def transform(self, X, y=None):
    return self.transform(X)

  def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
    return self.fit(X).transform(X)
```

And I have the "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error, which occurred at the fit method. I was able to make it right following some notes online:

```
class my_lb(LabelBinarizer):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def fit(self, X, y=None):
    super().fit(X)

  def transform(self, X, y=None):
    return super().transform(X)

  def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
    return super().fit(X).transform(X)
```

But my question is, how does it solve my problem? I can understand the cause in other posts here (which I can see are constructing an explicit infinite loop), but I read the codes of LabelBinarizer, and it looks pretty normal to me. I can't find anything that may cause an infinite loop.

```
def fit(self, y): 
        self.y_type_ = type_of_target(y)
        if 'multioutput' in self.y_type_:
             raise ValueError("Multioutput target data is not supported with "
                              "label binarization")
        if _num_samples(y) == 0:
            raise ValueError('y has 0 samples: %r' % y)
        self.sparse_input_ = sp.issparse(y)
        self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)
        return self
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? It will also help me know better when super is needed when I create an inheriting class.

Comment: If you inherit a class, and you want to use one of its methods unchanged, just don't override it in your class.  Delete your version of the method, and the parent class's version will automatically be called.  Your versions in which you call `super` don't really seem correct anyway either:  You're just discarding the `y` parameter, rather than passing it along to the parent class's method.

Comment: The second chunk was meant to solve a common issue in Pipeline Class where encoders don't really work well with pipeline methods. That's why you see my call method does nothing other than calling the corresponding parent function. The y parameter here is just a place holder to be consistent with other functions in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before it was changed to call `super()`, calling any one of the methods shown would have caused infinite recursion.  `fit` and `transform` are obvious, they just called themselves so if they were ever called, they would never return and you would exceed the maximum recursion depth.

`fit_transform`, on the other hand, was calling `self.fit(X).transform(X)`.  So the first thing it did was call `self.fit(X)`, which just called itself over and over until the error occurred.

The modified versions, on the other hand, pass the calls along to the parent class versions of `fit` and `transform`, via the call to `super()`, so they don't call themselves.  In fact, with those calls in place, you don't even need to call `super()` from `fit_transform`.

But the best fix is to simply delete the definitions of `fit` and `transform` in the derived class, and remove the call to `super()` from `fit_transform`, which isn't needed.

Comment: Ah I see, so essentially, what super does in my example is that the self passes the request to the parent function and collects whatever assigned to the parent object as its own. Am I thinking this right?

Comment: Will a call to `super()` instantiate a new object of super class always?

Comment: @fnosdy Yes, `super()` just lets you access methods of the parent class directly, bypassing your overrides.

Comment: @VivekKumar `super()` doesn't instantiate anything. It just lets you access methods of the parent class.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for clarification. :)